# expected ',' or '...' before 'array' in arduino 1.0.5

Tags: arrays, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to make a robot controlling program in arduino 1.0.5, and I keep getting this error but it makes no sense.

code:

```
String speeds[7] = {"Stop", "verySlow", "Slow", "ratherSlow", "ratherFast", "Fast", "veryFast"};
//                    0         15        30         45           60          75          90  


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("HELLO WORLD");
    Serial.println("Setting up\nOne moment please");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(2000);
    }
 }

void speedSetup(int direction, String speedName){ 
    int speedForServo;
    //int speedToUse = getStringIndex(speeds, speedName);
    if(direction == 1 ){

    }
}

//int getSrtringIndex(String[] array, String string){
//for(int i = 0; i < array.len()+1; i++){

//}
//}  

void loop(){}
```

Ignore the comments, they are mostly code to be added later.

Error copied from console:
                                                                                 sketch_may09b:4: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'array'

Comment: When I compile the code provided in the Arduino IDE I do not get any errors. Please check to make sure that you have provided all of the code.

Comment: no longer needed. I changed the program entirely and now it all works

Comment: strange, i always had a bunch